# Positioning div's from JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am creating a particle simulator and I am using css for the graphics. I created two different functions in JS to govern the X and Y positions on the page. To do this I simply

```
.particle2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position:absolute;
    top: yPosCalc;
    right: xPosCalc;
}
```

I understand this won't work at all but I wasn't sure how use this in css. I also tried to just use

```
<div style="width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position:absolute;
    top: yPosCalc;
    right: xPosCalc;"><p>particle1<p/>
<div/>
```

From that i just the exact same thing. My little balls just stay in the upper right corner they don't follow any of the functions rules. I am not sure how to use this correctly or if I can even do this. I don't know if this will help but here is both of the functions that are used a little bit earlier in the code.

```
function yPosCalc(yPos, timeInAir, initialVelocityY, initialYPos) {
   yPos = -4.8 * timeInAir * timeInAir + initialVelocityY + initialYPos;
   if (yPos <= -2500) {
       yPos = 2499;
    }
    return yPos;
}

function xPosCalc(xPos, timeInAir, intialVelocityX, intialXpos) {
     xPos = intialVelocityX * timeInAir * .384 - 480;
     /* This is for average webs size 960/2500 to get into right scale then
     minus half of 960 to bring it into the middle (from the right side) */
     if (xPos >= 2500) {
         xPos = -2499;
     }
     if (xPos <= -2500) {
         xPos = 2499;

     }
     return xPos;
}
```

Comment: If this is live, can you provide a link?

Comment: It is not live just something I am messing around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looked like a nice little project to do, so after some hacking and a few infinite loops losing all of my code, I came up with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ce9q6/9/) (I like to see atoms bouncing around on screens!).

By the x/y cooridnates I put above the start/stop buttons, you can see the code is doing what it should, but I could figure out a way to keep the bouncing ball in that small window.

So you know your equations better, and can fix it.

JS

```
var xPos = 60;
var yPos = 70;
var timeInAir = 2;
var initialVelocityX = 2;
var initialVelocityY = 3;
var initialXpos = 50;
var initialYpos = 50;
var timer;

$('.particle2').css({
                     top: initialYpos,
                     left: initialXpos
                     });

$('#startme').on('click', function(){
  timedCount();
                                     });

function timedCount()
{
  timer = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},1000);
  xPos = xPosCalc( xPos, timeInAir, initialVelocityX, initialXpos);
  yPos = yPosCalc( yPos, timeInAir, initialVelocityY, initialYpos);
  $('.putmehere').html("x= " + xPos.toFixed(1) + ' -- ' + "y= " + yPos.toFixed(1));
  timeInAir = timeInAir + 2;
  $('.particle2').css({
                       top: yPos,
                       left: xPos
                       });
}

function xPosCalc( xPos, timeInAir, intialVelocityX, initialXpos) {
     xPos = intialVelocityX * timeInAir * 0.384 - 480;
     return xPos;
}

function yPosCalc (yPos, timeInAir, initialVelocityY, initialYPos)
{
  yPos = -4.8 * timeInAir * timeInAir + initialVelocityY + initialYPos;
  return yPos;
}

$('#stopme').on('click', function(){
   clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To position an absolute div in Javascript use:

```
document.getElementById("divID").style.left="100px"; //new positon
document.getElementById("divID").style.top="100px"; //new positon
```

Comment: In that (new position) area can I put the function that determines the new position in

Comment: Yes you can but remeber to append the "px" to the end of it. e.g: style.left = xPosCalc(...)+"px";

Comment: Yes you can, but remember you need to call this code every time you want to recalculate the positions (probably several times per second)

Comment: Did you change the div's id to the id in the javascript? Is your javascript code in between <script></script> tags.

Comment: Put it in a timer using window.setInterval

Comment: Yes my js is between script tags but i must put the divs inside my script?. My functions fun in a for loop that runs 100 times

Comment: No the div must be outside the <script></script> tags. Just put a for loop in your <script></script> tag with the code above in your for loop pointing to your function.

Comment: If you are wanting a graphical representation of what is happening the best thing to use is a timer not a for loop, a for loop will execute the code so fast you wont see anything except the end position.